# Parse Telegram JSON message by line break

Tags: telegram-bot, mql4, mql5

I'd like to remove the line breaks from the telegram text message using MQL4 coding. I'd like to convert the text to a format that MT4 can use to place a trade.

The issue is that the telegram bot is reading the chat and the text is converted to a one-liner with the \n separator.  I need to split the different parts of the message into separate Int/Str/Double, etc. so that I can use them to place the trade using MQL4 code.

The message format is as follows:

"text":"XRPUSD\nBUYLIMIT\n0.15010\nSL 0.18000\nTP 0.14000"

This message comes in as msg.message_text but I don't see the actual message unless I use Postman. I just know the format from a JSON converter library.

Again, I need to split the different parts of the message into separate Int/Str/Double, etc, so that I can use them to place the trade using MQL4 code.

Hopefully, I am asking and presenting the data in a manner that makes sense.  Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use StringReplace method
Like this

```
string text="XRPUSD\nBUYLIMIT\n0.15010\nSL 0.18000\nTP 0.14000";
int replaced=StringReplace(text,"\n","/");
Print("Replaced: ", replaced,". Result=",text);
```

Comment: thanks very much.  It needs to be flexible enough to convert any instance of messages. These are the formats:
Line 543 msg.message_text=item["message"]["text"].ToStr();
Line 544 msg.message_text=StringDecode(msg.message_text);
Is line 544 doing what you are recommending?

Comment: I made a small modification and it works for removing the \n.  Any idea how the split the results into separate variables? Can the results be parsed?

Comment: Does any key value in your result?

Comment: I used the "string to_split" function and separated the individual values.  Now I need to be able to pull them into variables. Right now I can only print them. I need to either store them into variables or pull them from the "string to_split" array

Comment: Actually I don't know MQL I just read docs for your questions. Maybe you can use StringSplit.  Like this                                                                                                     
   string to_split="life_is_good";   // A string to split into substrings
   string sep="_";                // A separator as a character
   ushort u_sep;                 
   string result[];               // An array to get strings
   //--- Get the separator code
   u_sep=StringGetCharacter(sep,0);
   //--- Split the string to substrings
   int k=StringSplit(to_split,u_sep,result);

Comment: Yes correct.  It's just not storing them into values I can later use

Comment: How did you get the  "text" key from the array? I mean how did you parse the array?